# Apache Cordova project does not build in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, build

I was trying to build an app using Apache Cordova with Visual Studio 2013.

When I run the Blank app, I see below text in output and I cannot see the final result.

Output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp3, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1> GeneratedJavascript=scripts\index.js;scripts\index.js.map; scripts\platformOverrides.js;scripts\platformOverrides.js.map
1>  c:\users\behna\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp3\BlankCordovaApp3>call "C:\Program Files\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.7 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\PTHWPFNC.2FD\packages\vs-mda
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-mda
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 0.1.76
1>  ------ Current globally installed version: 0.1.76
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I set the path and environment variables (ADT_HOME, JAVA_HOME, ANT_HOME,...) correctly.